# UNNotificationAction not showing more than 2 in device

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I am working on interactive notifications in iOS. I made an app in which i am triggering local notifications on button click and have made a category with 3 actions in it. 
I execute the app in simulator and all the 3 buttons are visible. 
But in my testing device iPhone 5s, the last UNNotificationAction added in the category is not showing .

Here are my code snipets -

[image]

I searched the Apple doc too and found these :-

[image]

[image]

I don't understand by what they mean - "When minimal space is available, only the first two is displayed from array."

What do they mean by minimal space and why the Action is not showing ??